# peewee.OperationalError: no such function: json

Tags: python, peewee

**Python version: 3.8.3**

**Peewee version: 3.13.3**

I want to create an object which include a JSONField,

```
db = SqliteExtDatabase('../db.sqlite', pragmas=(('journal_mode', 'wal'), ('foreign_keys', 1)))

class Msg(BaseModel):
    id = AutoField()
    detail = JSONField()

def insert_msg(detail: dict):
    msg = Msg.create(detail=detail)
    msg.save()
```

but when I call the method *insert_msg({"name":"abc"})*, an error comes out

```
peewee.OperationalError: no such function: json
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you add the rest of the traceback? It's possible your error is related to or similar in nature to: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/1666 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the sqlite json1 extension installed. Here are some links which may help:

- http://charlesleifer.com/blog/compiling-sqlite-for-use-with-python-applications/
- https://sqlite.org/json1.html
- https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3 (pip install pysqlite3-binary for pre-compiled/statically-linked pysqlite with json ext)